# Excel: Trying to return value from separate workbook based on matching ID and greater than less than range

Tags: excel

I'm new to excel so bear with me.
This problem involves two separate workbooks. My goal is to populate one column with data from the source workbook based on an exact ID match, as well as being in a range of two numbers. In the workbook to be populated, column H is where the data will be populated. Column B holds the ID value, and column D has a number value that is to be in the middle of the number range.

In the source workbook, column B has the ID value to be matched, column C has the number value to be greater than, and column D has the number value to be less than. Lastly, the return value is in column E. The idea is to first find the range of rows (Normally around 15 rows) that have an exact ID match, and then find the first row with a number range that our lookup number falls in the middle of. This first matched row would be the row that column E data is pulled from.

So far I have tried Xlookups, as well as index-match formulas but have had no luck so far. Any idea what formula could accomplish this?
Let me know if you need any other info or if I need to clarify anything!

Thanks,
Tettchra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use filter to return the correct arrays to the XLOOKUP:

```
=XLOOKUP(H2,FILTER(B:B,A:A=G2),FILTER(D:D,A:A=G2),"",-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this seems to work perfectly! Thank you so much, especially for the fast response, this has been struggle for me to figure out for some time now. I'm not even completely sure I understand how this formula works, but it's done the job!